# How to display XML data (extracted from PHP) in an Adobe Air Application?

Tags: php, xml, apache-flex, air

I would like to create a small Adobe Air application which would extract XML data from my site and display it in my Adobe air application.

I have the xml part setup, when i run the xml file, it displays the results in the browser. Now what i need is to display the same results in my adobe air application.

For e.g. I have a simple form

```
<form name="review" action="admin_xml.php" method="post">
<textarea name="xml" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>    
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Request">
</form>
```

I enter the following XML data into the form.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetOrdersIds version="1.0">
    <Credentials>
        <Username>my_user</Username>
        <Password>my_pass</Password>
    </Credentials>
    <Criterions>
        <OrderNumber></OrderNumber>
        <NameEmail></NameEmail>
        <Keyword></Keyword>
        <StartDate>2009-01-01</StartDate>
        <EndDate></EndDate>
        <OrderStatus></OrderStatus>
        <ShipToCountry></ShipToCountry>
        <ShipToState></ShipToState>
        <CreditCardType></CreditCardType>
    </Criterions>
</GetOrdersIds>
```

---

When i submit the form, i get all the order id's from 2009-01-01 till date and it get displayed in the browser.

Is there a way to run that HTML form in an adobe air application such that I enter the XML element values it should go through the admin_xml.php file and get the results.
 I dont want to enter the XML Skeleton again and again. I only want to able to enter the values for those elements.

Are there any tutorials or books which deal with this topic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Building an XML viewer on AIR with Flex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/xml_viewer_on_air.html) describes how to build an application that "translates" a specific xml format to a specific display format.

[Using AIR for XSLT Processing](http://blogs.adobe.com/briggs/2008/05/using_air_for_xslt_processing.html) describes how you can utilize the xslt processor and built-in html engine.

Comment: Can you recommend any books on this topic ?

Comment: No idea, but guess where I found a list... ;-)   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96757/what-are-the-best-books-for-flex-and-adobe-air